# How do I create a file-scope class in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I left the original, so people can understand the context for the comments.  Hopefully, this example will better help explain what I am after.

Can I create a class in Obj-C that has file-scope visibility?

For example, I have written a method-sqizzling category on NSNotificationCenter which will automatically remove any observer when it deallocs.

I use a helper class in the implementation, and to prevent name collision, I have devised a naming scheme.  The category is NSNotificationCenter (WJHAutoRemoval), so the private helper class that is used in this code is named...

```
WJH_NSNotification_WJHAutoRemoval__Private__BlockObserver
```

That's a mouthful, and currently I just do this...

```
#define BlockObserver WJH_NSNotification_WJHAutoRemoval__Private__BlockObserver
```

and just use BlockObserver in the code.

However, I don't like that solution.

I want to tell the compiler, "Hey, this class is named Bar.  My code will access it as Bar, but I'm really the only one that needs to know.  Generate a funky name yourself, or better yet, don't even export the symbol since I'm the only one who should care."

For plain C, I would is "static" and for C++ "namespace { }"

What is the preferred/best/only way to do this in Obj-C?

**Original Question**

I want to use a helper class inside the implementation of another.  However, I do not want external linkage.  Right now, I'm just making the helper class name painfully unique so I will not get duplicate linker symbols.

I can use static C functions, but I want to write a helper class, with linker visibility only inside the compilation unit.

For example, I'd like to have something like the following in multiple .m files, with each "Helper" unique to that file, and no other compilation unit having linker access.  If I had this in 10 different files, I'd have 10 separate classes.

```
@interface Helper : NSObject
...
@end

@implementation Helper : NSObject
...
@end
```

I have been unable to find even a hint of this anywhere, and my feeble attempts at prepending "static" to the interface/implementation were wrought with errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider making the helper a category of the main class?

Comment: That is too invasive for this purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "too invasive?" This sounds like a reasonable use case for categories and/or class extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to do what you want because of the Objective-C Runtime.  All of your classes are loaded into the runtime and multiple classes with the same name will conflict with each other.

Objective-C is a dynamic language. Unlike other languages which bind method calls at compile time, Objective-C does method resolution at invocation (every invocation).  The runtime finds the class in the runtime and then finds the method in the class.  The runtime can't support distinct classes with the same name and Objective-C doesn't support namespaces to seperate your classes.

If your `Helper` classes are different in each case they will need distinct class names (multiple classes with the same name sounds like a bad idea to me, in any language).  If they are the same then why do you want to declare them separately.

I think you need to rethink your strategy as what you are trying to do doesn't sound very Objective-C or Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make a class "hidden." As mttrb notes, classes are accessible by name through the runtime. This isn't like C and C++ where class are just symbols that are resolved to addresses by the linker. Every class is injected into the class hierarchy.

But I'm unclear why you need this anyway. If you have a private class `WJHAutoRemovalHelper` or whatever, it seems very unlikely to collide with anyone else any more than private Apple classes or private 3rdparty framework classes collide. There's no reason to go to heroic lengths to make it obscure; prefixing with `WJHAutoRemoval` should be plenty to make it unique. Is there some deeper problem you're trying to fix?

BTW as an aside: How are you implementing the rest of this? Are you ISA-swizzling the observer to override its dealloc? This seems a lot of tricky code to make a very small thing slightly more convenient.

---

Regarding the question of "private" classes, what you're suggesting is possible if you do it by hand, but there really is no reason for it. You can generate a random, unique classname, call `objc_allocateClassPair()` and `objc_registerClassPair` on it, and then assign that to a `Class` variable at runtime. (And then call `class_addMethod` and `class_addIvar` to build it up. You can then always refer to it by that variable when you need it. It's still accessible of course at runtime by calling `objc_getClassList`, but there won't be a symbol for the classname in the system.

But this is a lot of work and complexity for no benefit. ObjC does not spend much time worrying about protecting the program from itself the way C++ does. It uses naming conventions and compiler warning to tell you when you're doing things wrong, and expects that as a good programmer you're going to avoid doing things wrong.

Comment: I had always assumed the dynamic nature of the language prevented this, so I just accepted it.  However, as I've learned more about the Obj-C internals, I do not think there is a technical reason this can not be supported.  Since I don't like having to provide those long names, I thought I'd investigate it again.  I could not find a positive answer one way or the other.  Being a very old C++ guy, I keep coming up with reasons to code straight .mm but I've refused to do it so I can learn the Obj-C way (plus, before I was a C++ guy, I did all my graduate work in LisP and Smalltalk-80).

Comment: Like I say, you don't need to provide really long names. Just use reasonable prefixes. You certainly should not code in straight .mm. It has many problems from poor tool support (especially in gdb) to slow compiles, to slower ARC code (and higher memory requirements in ARC). ObjC++ is purely a bridging language; for that it's quite useful. But it should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: As for the notification stuff, I am using the method swizzling techniques right out of your book.  The notification methods are pretty simple.  They just add an OnDealloc block to the observer so that it is removed when the observer deallocs (I have a category to add blocks to an object that get executed when it deallocs) .  However, for the add/block method NotificationCenter returns an opaque type that it creates and RETAINS under ARC.  I have a simple helper class that holds the opaque id returned by NC.  In its dealloc, it removes itself from the NC.  I return the helper to the caller.

Comment: You will note that in the method swizzling section I say to avoid this technique for production code :D What do you mean by adding an "OnDealloc" block? Are you ISA-swizzling the observer?

Comment: I been unable to find a proclamation against it (but have seen some of the examples of swizzling dealloc that have been rejected).  I have an ISA swizzled version as well, but I prefer the method swizzled one.  It just integrates so well.  Link and go.  I'm installing the on-dealloc block with objc_SetAccociatedObject.  It gets called at the end of the allocation process (WWDC 2011 322) so you can't really access the object anymore but I don't need that.  I'd be happy to send you my code if you want to take a look at it.  Probably should take this off-line though.